# How to use the sync between computers in Software Center

Tags: software-center, oneconf

Am trying to sync between 2 computers with Software Center but it is confusing. I already logged in in both using the same account but they do not appear to show in the others list. So maybe a step by step guide to how to use this would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use one-conf to sync between two or more computers.

To use one-conf, login into your Ubuntu One account on all the computers that you want to sync. Then, open software center and click on 'File' menu. And then, click the option 'Sync Between Computers...'

[image]

After you click that, a sidebar would appear on the left side. It will only list the local computer.

On the bottom, there is a button, clicking which would display a dialog box reading `Start syncing <system-name>`. Click the button and your computers would then be synced between them. Only after clicking the button would the computers associated with the Ubuntu One account would be displayed on both the computers.

[image]

Comment: Per user [Chelmite](http://askubuntu.com/users/65690/chelmite): *But...there's only a Stop Syncing button (both on my computer and in your picture) that shuts down the Sync.*

Comment: @Seth -- did you manage to get this running? I have the same problem -- I only have the "Stop Syncing" button and the <system-name> is the same as the current computer, I don't see any other computers in that list.

Comment: I too have only "Stop syncing" button, even though I can see both computers in the list.