# How to set pre-installed applications in an Ubuntu installation?

Tags: installation, custom-distributions

Is there a way to have an installation of Ubuntu with all the usual programs or pre-defined ones?

Eg: *Blender, Gimp, VLC, Firezila*

I'm having to install Ubuntu a few times and Id like a preset install.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to create and maintain an installation that may change as you add or remove favorite programs, another option is to save the installed progrms using either synaptic, the command-line, or a feature in the Software Center + Ubuntu one called "Sync between computers."

If you use the software center, it has a feature in the "File" menu called "Sync between computers" where you can use your Ubuntu One account to keep apps synched between multiple computers.  [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/74526/39753) has instructions for it.

If you use synaptic, there's an option in the File menu to "Save Markings" and "Read Markings".  This will save all the installed programs to a file.

From the command line, there's a way to do it, also.  There's an [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/17823/39753) article that explains this process.

Unfortunately, none of these methods will install anything that was installed manually rather than using the repository.  But there are drawbacks to any method.

Answer (score 3):

Try <s>[Remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/ubuntu.html)</s> *(No longer being maintained or updated)* [Relinux](https://launchpad.net/relinux), which is a fork of Remastersys. You can find a tutorial [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/creating-your-own-distributable-ubuntu-dvd-relinux), though I haven't gone through it.

*Will leave this here for historic purposes:*

Ive used this before with great results. You can do a whole back up with the command:

```
sudo remastersys backup
```

Which will back up your /home, accounts, passwords, etc.

Or make a copy that wont have your information on it:

```
remastersys dist
```

Which will make a copy that you can give to other people, that will include updates/programs etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the following link will show you how: [LINK](http://www.howtogeek.com/?post_type=post&p=109736)

Comment: Link-only answers are considered low-value in Stack Exchange because if/when the link moves or "dies", then the entire answer is rendered useless.  I realize there are multiple steps in your recommended guidance, but ideally the steps should be transferred into the answer so that your answer has truly timeless value.