# Is there a way to sync my laptop's Ubuntu install with a jumpdrive Ubuntu install?

Tags: sync, usb-drive

So I'm doing a fresh install of Ubuntu on my laptop right now. I also have a jumpdrive with Ubuntu installed on it with a persistent setup.

What I would like is to be able to plug the jumpdrive into my laptop and have the installs sync certain data. I don't want docs and such to sync of course, but I would like some software to sync with installs and updates, mostly security and recovery stuff. Here's an example of what I would like to happen:

I already have TestDisk installed on my jumpdrive but I haven't booted the drive in a while. I plug it in to my laptop where TestDisk has been updated and Wireshark has been installed. I would like the jumpdrive to check to see what has changed on the laptop install (in this case TestDisk has updated and Wireshark has been installed) and make those changes to the jumpdrive.

Is there any kind of software to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/74526/how-to-use-the-sync-between-computers-in-software-center

Comment: Nope, we're looking at different issues. My solution needs to be able to update the software on the jumpdrive install without booting the jumpdrive install. Essentially, I want to laptop install to keep the jumpdrive install up-to-date rather than having to boot the jumpdrive to sync over the web.