# Can I create a setup file out of already installed files?

Tags: package-management

I have used an Android phone and was very much impressed to learn that it is based on Linux. I had an application there named "Super Manager" from play store. It has many features but my favorite is that it can convert installed apps into .apk files and using those I can install the same apps on other phones as well either through memory card or through backup.

I was wondering if the same feature would be available in Ubuntu, because I have another PC which doesn't have internet so I can't download applications directly from Ubuntu Software Center. I am pretty new in Linux environment as I have been using Windows so long, so asked this just out of curiosity. Help will be much appreciated. Thanks a lot friends.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a list of installed packages we may use the inbuilt command line Debian package manager **dpkg** [[manpage for the `dpkg` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/dpkg)] with the option `--get-selections`. Below command will generate a file `packages.list` of all installed packages (including the default packages) in the directory you opened the terminal in:

```
dpkg --get-selections > packages.list
```

For a more elaborate answer on how to further use this list for backup purposes see

- [How to backup settings and list of installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc)

We may also use the sync function from the Ubuntu Software Center to syncronize installed applications between computers:

- [How to use the sync between computers in Software Center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74526/how-to-use-the-sync-between-computers-in-software-center)

Answer (score -2):

there is a small tiny script named cde which, once ran, it can compile any installed app and all its dependencies and libraries in use into a portable app folder. Then you can copy that folder to your other machine and then you have two options, or use them as portable or copy by hand any file into its proper location. To do the last you may follow the portable folder file system as a guide to copy to the machine own files. Be careful to not overwrite newer versions of any library.

Comment: This answer asserts that there is a program that does something like what the OP asks, but it should say how to get and use that program.