# Is there a way to cloud backup applications?

Tags: ubuntu-one, backup

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10. I have downloaded most appropriate applications from various categories of Ubuntu Software Center as per my need.

It took a lot of effort to search, download and try each application and select among those which suited me best. For example, I downloaded English dictionaries like goldendict, artha, stardict etc., tried them all and selected artha for my personal use.

Now when I have made my collection I don't want to go through this type of searching and downloading in future again.

Is there a way to backup my applications (at least name or along with its data if possible) like in Android or iOS so that I can view my installed applications in one place for easy access for future installation if needed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the sync between computers in Software Center](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74526/how-to-use-the-sync-between-computers-in-software-center)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is very easy to do from Ubuntu Software Center**

- Open software center and click on 'File' menu.
- And then, click the option 'Sync Between Computers...'

After you click that, a sidebar would appear on the left side. It will list software in the local computer and the list will be uploaded in the Ubuntu One cloud.

[image]

See the **Last sync** at the bottom left corner to verify the sync is complete.

If you have two computers you can repeat this process. At that time the left panel will show your our other computer as well as this one. Then you can select apps installed in one computer and install them in the other one.

See the related question [How to use the sync between computers in Software Center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74526/how-to-use-the-sync-between-computers-in-software-center)

**Update: April 4, 2014**

Canonical has announced that **[Ubuntu One will not be supported in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and later. The Ubuntu One service will be closed down and the data in the cloud will be deleted.](http://blog.canonical.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/)** The cloud backup and sync of the list of applications installed in multiple Ubuntu computers described above will not be available.

**I do not recommend this answer any more.**

Hope this helps